# Excel Change "x h x m" Format into minutes only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am Trying to change the Excel cells which contain hours and minutes with "h" and "m" into minutes only. The Problem here that the letters h & m are in the cell.

What i need it to look like:

**2h 30m  --> 150**

**4h      --> 240**

**51m     --> 51**

Please help me out. thanks in advance.. !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

[image]

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("h";A1));VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";"");"h";":");"m";""))*24*60;VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"m";"")))
```

Notice there is an IF to separate cases when there is only minutes from cases when there is also hours (calculus is different)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=1440*TEXTAFTER(":0:"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"m",""),"h",":"),":",-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

So find the "h" to get the hours like so:

```
=left(A2,find("h",A2,1)-1)
```

Then multiply the result by 60 (as 60 minutes in an hour)

For minutes:

```
=mid(A2,find("h",a2,1)+1,2)
```

This assumes that minutes is double digit as per your example, you could make it more precise by finding the position of the "m" and calculating the difference.

Then sum the result to get minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Another legacy formula:-

```
=1440*SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*h*"),"","0h")&A1,"h",":"),"m","")
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]